# Dependency org.json:json:jar is missing

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I have a problem with the project I am working on. Until Tuesday everything seemed to be fine when I was building and running my project. Today I wanted to run the project and I received this error message:

```
  [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
    [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.json:json:jar is missing. @ 
    line 57, column 21
```

After I added the version, the build is now failing due to this exception:

```
[WARNING] 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/web/support/SpringBootServletInitializer
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:491)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Edit: this is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml vers
```

ion="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.X</groupId>
<artifactId>spring</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>Y</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot JPA - PostgreSQL</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <finalName>ZZZ</finalName>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                        <directory>../angular/dist/</directory>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you share your POM file ? My initial guess is you are missing version for the `org.json:json` dependency.

Comment: unrelated: your pdfbox version is outdated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like You have more than one `org.json:json` dependency on your classpath.

Looking at it:
`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test` depends on
 `com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path`which in turn brings 
`org.json:json` which is much older than your version (v. **20140107**)

You could try excluding this transitive dependency from `spring-boot-starter-test`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

... but it's possible that there is something within `json-path` which depends on something from the older `json` library, which is no longer in the newer version, so proceed with caution and test everything thoroughly.

There is also a chance that something else brings `org.json:json`.

To verify, please run `mvn dependency:tree` and search in the produced output for `org.json:json`.

Comment: I can't even run mvn dependency:tree and not see this ERROR related to this ('dependencies.dependency.version' for org.json:json:jar is missing. @ line 59, column 21). I tried the exclusion, but does not work

Comment: I deleted the repository files from .m2 folder and I tried to run **mvn clean install**, and it worked for 3 seconds and after that the same error popped out. I will try to rewrite my pom.xml file.

Comment: add version to your explicit import, and then run the `mvn dependency:tree`

Answer (score 0):

The version definition (`<version>RELEASE</version>`) of your spring boot parent is incorrect.

The correct way to define a spring boot parent is -

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>

    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

Comment: I tried to add the version, but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 2.0 released on 1 Mar 2018. Before that the latest RELEASE version for Spring Boot was 1.5.x.

Set the Spring Boot version to 1.5.12.RELEASE and try again:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.12.RELEASE</version>

    <relativePath />
</parent>
```